JPA 1.0 Type Mismatch oneToOne with Embedded ID
I have an issue with a OneToOne association in Hibernate/JPA 1.0, Java 6.
@MapsId would probably be the thing I need but unfortunately I can't upgrade anything, this is a legacy project.
I have 3 tables
DECA
DECB
ADM
DECA has a composite PK with DECA_PERS, DECA_ORD, DECA_ART
DECB has a composite PK with DECB_PERS, DECB_ORD, DECB_ART
ADM has a composite PK with PERS, ORD, ART.
There is no FK between any of those tables, client deactivated them, but there was FK from DECA to ADM and DECB to ADM. ADM entries sometimes refer to DECA (when ART value is 30) and sometimes to DECB(when ART value is 20). All entries of DECA have corresponding entry in ADM, same thing for DECB entries.
In java it goes like this
@Entity
@Table("DECA")
public class Deca implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private DecaId id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Adm adm;

// GETTER SETTERS AND SERIAL UID 

}

Then ID of DECA :
@Embeddable
public class DecaId implements Serializable {

@Column(name="DECA_PERS", nullable=false)
private String pers;
@Column(name="DECA_ORD",nullable = false)
private String ord;
@Column(name="DECA_ART",nullable=false)
private String art;
//getter and setter
}

Then DEC B
@Entity
@Table("DECB")
public class Deca implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private DecaId id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Adm adm;

// GETTER SETTERS AND default SERIAL UID 

}

Dec B id
@Embeddable
public class DecbId implements Serializable {

@Column(name="DECB_PERS",nullable=false)
private String pers;
@Column(name="DECB_ORD",nullable=false)
private String ord;
@Column(name="DECB_ART",nullable=false)
private String art;

//getter and setter and default serial version UID

}

Adm
 @Entity 
 @Table("ADM")
 public class Adm implements Serializable {

 @EmbeddedId
 private AdmId id;


 // Getter setter and serialized UID (i tried to put some @OneToOne/mappedBy fields but did 
  not make a difference)
}

Adm id
@Embeddable
public class AdmId implements Serializable{

@Column(name="PERS", nullable = false)
private String pers;
@Column(name="ORD", nullable= false)
private String ord;
@Column(name="ART", nullable = false)
private String art;

//Getter and setter
}

First it did not persist automatically (even when i put a cascade.all ) so I added a mapping in the EAO class. Now it persists but when I perform a read operation i have an error, saying typemismatch, it expected admId but got DecbId, and the thing is i don't even ask for adm, i only want to read from decB. Same thing occurs when I got things from decA, it says it expects admId but got decaId.
I cant paste the error log since i changed names because this is a work project and I'm not really allowed to divulgate infos. I also tried with classical joincolumns, and it always says the same thing.
Sorry for my english I am french and try my best.
